# How may I save image from database as tiff file?

Tags: sql, image, save, tiff

I am trying to retrieve an image from a database and save it as a tiff file. The initial image format of the database image was tiff.

```
Dim imgInBytes() As Byte = CType(sqlReader.GetValue(11), Byte())
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(imgInBytes)
img = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
img.Save(path & "\" & fn)
ms.Close()
img.Dispose()
```

Using the aforementioned code, I have been able to generate a file. The problem is, the image can not be viewed. I get the following message:

> Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the picture is
>   being edited in another program.

How may I save image from database as tiff file? What changes to my code need to be made?

Comment: Try writing the bytes (`imgInBytes`) directly to disk. No need to create an image in your program.

Comment: Hi HaraldK, Thank you for your answer, it works. File.WriteAllBytes(path & "\" & fn, imgInBytes) resolves my issue.